# html2pdf.js prints blank pdf in ios devices

Tags: javascript, html2pdf

```
function downloadPDF(){
    apply_print_style();

    var element = document.getElementById('LIMS_ROI_calculator');
    var opt = {
    margin:       0.2,
    filename:     'LIMS_ROI_calculator.pdf',
    pagebreak: { mode: ['avoid-all', 'css', 'legacy'], before:'#page_02',},
    jsPDF:{ unit: 'in', format: 'a3', orientation: 'portrait' }
    };

    // New Promise-based usage:
    html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();
}
```

html2pdf.js prints blank pdf in ios devices

Comment: Can you precise which iOs device? There are some advices [here](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/issues/397). For example you can try first to comment `mode: ['avoid-all', 'css', 'legacy']`, then if it doesn't work you can try to add `compress: true,` in jsPDF options. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 setTimeout(function() {
    html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();
  }, 1000);
```

or:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // call html2pdf() here
}
```

also:

```
jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' }
```

try a4 vs a3

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the library.  The reason is that html2pdf.js renders all of the content to a single html canvas element before converting to a pdf.  If the size of the document exceeds the browser's own limit on the size of an html canvas element, the pdf just ends up being blank.

This is an issue on all devices and browsers, but particularly shows up on iOS because iOS has a smaller canvas size limit.

You can use [html3pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html3pdf) which is a fork of html2pdf.js with some bug fixes, including this one.  html3pdf renders every page on its own canvas, so there is no limit to the number of pages you can have (although it is slower).